# Can I reverse tether my Android device to my phone using Bluetooth PAN or DUN?

Tags: bluetooth, internet, reverse-tether

I have a Sony Ericsson K800i phone that supports both bluetooth PAN and DUN.

Is there any way to share my phone's internet to my tablet (cheap achinese Aishuo A820 with Android 2.3.1, rooted). For now I don't care if the method requires root because the tablet **is** rooted, but if it's possible to do it without root would be great.

I've looked at https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7817/reverse-tether-on-android-via-bluetooth-pan but it only appears to cover PAN (not DUN) and asks about tethering a phone with a PC. Since I'd like to tether two mobile devices I'm guessing that there will be fewer software options available to me.

I'm ok with writing shell scripts and I have some Linux experience, but not with bluetooth.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reverse tether on Android via Bluetooth PAN?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7817/reverse-tether-on-android-via-bluetooth-pan)

Comment: yes. I read that, but it's only about PAN and I think that extending it with DUN is enough to ask a separate question. Plus the question you are referring is about a PC (mostly) and my question is about a phone which has limited options (can't install software on it)

Answer (score 1):

On my **rooted** device I was able to start connection **once** and it never worked again. Command is:

```
android# pand --connect XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
android# netcfg bnep0 dhcp
```

alternatively if you know the address of remote device  - let's say 192.168.101.1

```
android# ifconfig bnep0 192.168.101.1
android# route add default gw 192.168.101.1 dev bnep0
android# setprop net.dns1 192.168.101.1
```

I'm not sure why it stopped working for me. Maybe I'll restore factory image, root it and try again.