# How to Bluetooth tether Motorola Droid 3 (Android 2.3.4) to HTC One

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, reverse-tether, bluetooth-tethering

I have figured out how to enable the HTC to share it's internet via bluetooth:

Mobile Network Sharing -> Bluetooth Tethering [checked on]

But I am unable to find a way to allow the Droid 3 to consume the internet via bluetooth. I can get the Droid 3 to broadcast using 3rd part apps, btu can't figure out how to consume.

Note, this Droid 3 is my old phone that I am still using in my car as I can't mount my HTC One for non-technical reasons.

This looks like a duplicate of [another reverse tethering issue](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19594/can-i-reverse-tether-my-android-device-to-my-phone-using-bluetooth-pan-or-dun) which is a duplicate itself, but the answer listed can't be found.

Answer (score 1):

WiFi tethering may be a better option. On your HTC One, go to:

Settings > More... > Tethering & portable hotspot > Portable WiFi hotspot

Comment: actually I don't think I can do that as then I would have to buy the wifi hotspot feature. I'm trying to connect teh two phones for free

Comment: In stock android tethering does not cost any money. You should contact your carrier or device manufacturer to find out any modifications they may have made to Android that could cost you money. If your carrier or manufacturer has made modifications to the methods of stock tethering, there are apps that will allow you to tether without paying (I have not used these apps and am unsure of their quality) One of these apps is here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.diyphonegadgets.wifihotspot&hl=en