# How I can reverse-tether my tablet using my phone’s mobile broadband with bluetooth DUN, without rooting?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, bluetooth, tablet, reverse-tether, samsung-galaxy-tab-s-10.5

I have a [phone](http://www.samsung.com/fr/consumer/mobile-phones/mobiles/bar/GT-B2100SRIXEF) which run java for the [J2ME](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/javame/index.html) platform not android ones.
When I pair it with my laptop, I can use the [phone](http://www.samsung.com/fr/consumer/mobile-phones/mobiles/bar/GT-B2100SRIXEF) to connect internet using [mobile broadband](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_broadband#GSM_family) connection *(I pick my provider in a list on the laptop to autocomplete the parameters)*.

However when I pair it on my Samsung Galaxy tab S, I don't have this option, even when there is no Wi-Fi access point.
There are lot of apps to convert you android phone into a server for this. But I own a tablet with android 5 *(only Wi-Fi and bluetooth connection)*, and I would like to use my classic mobile phone as access point over bluetooth. I know how to configure the phone since I already use it on my Linux laptop. But I don’t know how to use my tablet as a DUN client, and I couldn’t find an app on the play store for that.
For those who still don’t what is beeing asked here, here’s a [tutorial](https://wiki.debian.org/UseYourCellPhoneAsModem) I use for a non wizard tethering on Debian *(I couldn’t find a android equivalent)*.

So, how I can connect Samsung galaxy tab S 8.4 to internet over bluetooth with my mobile phone's connection?

## Update :

Here’s my provider parameters in my case :
**dial-up number value** : "*99#"
**APN value** : "Free"

**Authentication method** : Store
**Username value** : "Free"
**Password value** : "Free"

**DUN channel value** : "0"
**Connection method** : [GPRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Packet_Radio_Service)
**PIN method** : Store
**PIN value** : null
**Provider proxy address value** : "212.27.40.225"
**Provider proxy port value** : "80"

But on most OS, *(for laptop, including old windows)* you just get a country selector, then you pick-up your mobile provider in a list and the connection parameters are filled up for you.

***Note***: As the device is still new I want to keep the long time warranty option.
BlueVPN+ seems to indirectly allow what I need without rooting, but the program is not free.

Comment: Sum up : I often use bluetooth-tethering trough my phone’s connection on my laptop and I would like to do the same with my tablet. The aim is to access my e-mails when there is no Wi-Fi access point.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I reverse tether my Android device to my phone using Bluetooth PAN or DUN?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19594/can-i-reverse-tether-my-android-device-to-my-phone-using-bluetooth-pan-or-dun)

Comment: @RyanConrad : I don’t think a rooted answer is enough to mark the answer as a duplicate. Especially in that case.

Comment: Ok, that's why it's called a 'possible duplicate', either way it is related. Here is another is very similar to your issue as well: [TCP/IP tethering over Bluetooth](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24332/tcp-ip-tethering-over-bluetooth)

Comment: While waiting for an answer to your question, you should also take a look at [other questions with similar issues](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Breverse-tether%5D+bluetooth+is%3Aquestion+answers%3A1) and see if any of those help you.

Comment: @RyanConrad : No, because there is the connection type in more of bluetooth-tethering. It allowed me to view the review the existing answers quickly : http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Breverse-tether%5D+bluetooth+is%3Aquestion+DUN http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Breverse-tether%5D+bluetooth+is%3Aquestion+mobile+broadband http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Breverse-tether%5D+bluetooth+is%3Aquestion+GPRS . It also seems the answer for rooted phones will not work for me, because it doesn’t ask providers parameters, nor provider brand name.

Comment: This question is off-topic here. This is not an android related question, every answer is going to be "wrong". This site is for android related questions.

Comment: @RyanConrad : Either You or I didn’t understand : I’m not ***asking how to set up my phone for tethering***, since I already know it. I want ***my android device to use the non android phone’s built-in GPRS modem*** *(which is something most 2G only GSM only phones have)* via bluetooth. It work by using [this service](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/services/Pages/ServiceViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.service.internet_protocol_support.xml) and the following [**official** service classes](https://www.bluetooth.org/en-us/specification/assigned-numbers/service-discovery) : 0x1103 0x1204 0x112D.

Comment: Also **Sighh**, What a *shame* for android that peoples don’t understand. when pairing the phone with a computer makes the OS propose to use it as an INTERNET access immediately and where the configuration is just matter of picking up the provider in a list **:-(**. *(This works with GNOME KDE and windows up to XP)*.

Answer (score 2):

So I was doing a bit of research on this.

TLDR; You will not be able to use your phone's GSM to connect your tablet to the internet.

In order for your Android device to be able to connect to another device, via bluetooth, to get an internet connection, you need an android device that supports [DUN (Dial-up Networking) or PAN (Personal Area Networking)](http://techsupport.dension.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/48/0/what-are-pan-and-dun). Which most android devices do support. You also need the "host" device to also support DUN. Your phone, on the other hand, does not support DUN nor does it support PAN.

Here are the bluetooth profiles that [your phone supports](http://www.samsung.com/fr/consumer/mobile-phones/mobiles/bar/GT-B2100SRIXEF):

> #### Bluetooth Profiles:
>
> - A2DP
> - AVRCP
> - BPP
> - FTP
> - GAP
> - Handsfree
> - Headset
> - HFP
> - HSP
> - SAP

The reason that you are able to get your laptop to tether via bluetooth with your device is because Windows supports tethering via SPP.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_stack):

> Note : The Windows XP/Vista Windows Vista/Windows 7 Bluetooth stack supports the following Bluetooth profiles natively: PANU, SPP, DUN, HID, HCRP.

While Android does have support for SPP, it does not support tethering via SPP. This is only supported via DUN/PAN. There is an [active issue around this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39637) that is listed as assigned to a developer but has had no activity since June 23rd 2013.

> I bought the Nexus 7 3G as a professional development tool to make bluetooth applications but from what I see, I'm stuck with an expensive paper weight. The SPP profile is used by many companies to connect there devices (robots, OBDII scanners, Microcontrollers, dataloggers.. e.t.c) to tablets. This protocol should have worked with the Nexus 7 but does not.
> It did not work with android 4.2.1 and does not work with android 4.2.2. It used to work with android 4.1.2.
> Not everyone can downgrade to 4.1.2 since it is not available to all devices.
>
> Now we all have to wait until android 5 comes out, but I do not think this will be fixed since google does not take us seriously.
>
> Don't you guys tests your products before you market them or do you just let the end user do the testing for you?

Comment: note : since I upgraded to Windows XP service pack 2, I can't use windows anymore for this *(but that's why I use KDE)* because becuase higher version of Windows only support classic modem dial-up, and try to use the phone modem as a classic 56k modem *(non GPRS bluetooth modem)*. I also runned`sdptool`on my phone and it appear you where wrong on the supported bluetooth profiles *(the hex number coressponding to DUN appear in the list)*. DUN also reaquie a supplementary autorisation *(which my phone prompt before each acess for each device in more of pairing)*.

Comment: I also successfully connected to INTERNET, with blueVPN, but there is an [issue in android 4.4 kitcat](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62714) which makes you need to create the connection while being already connected to a Wi-Fi AP. When the connection was established it prompted me to buy blueVPN+.

Comment: `Your phone, on the other hand, does not support DUN nor does it support PAN.` is wrong. When I pair my phone with my laptop The phone prompt me if I allow the laptop to use DUN0. Most IOS and android devices doesn’t support BT/DUN *(this is something you can check by listing the bluetooth profiles of the device)*. I can no longer use windows for pairing as XPSP2 and higher try to use the modem as a regular one instead of GPRS.

Comment: I finally discovered my device support PAN *(reverse tethering over bluetooth work with my laptop)* but not DUN and my phone support DUN but not PAN.

Answer (score 1):

Install and use easytether. I use this on a wide range of devices across multiple operation systems.

Site link : http://www.mobile-stream.com/easytether/android.html

### Features

- USB and Bluetooth tethering for Windows 10/8.1/8/7/Vista/XP computers (32-/64-bit)
- USB and Bluetooth tethering for Android 5.0 (down to 4.0.3) tablets including Kindle Fire
- USB tethering for Mac OS X 10.10 (down to 10.4) on Intel and legacy PowerPC hardware
- USB tethering support for Linux (Ubuntu, Fedora etc) computers on Intel, ARM (Raspberry Pi), PowerPC hardware
- Unique USB tethering support for FreeBSD computers and embedded boards
- Unique USB tethering support for OpenWRT-based routers
- Does not require root access on the smartphone
- UDP support for games, for L2TP VPN (not PPTP!) and for some IM apps
- PS3, XBox 360 or Wii tethering via Windows/OS X Internet Connection Sharing feature
- Free lifetime upgrades for the full version
- Implemented as a normal NAT application with full TCP and UDP support
  Compatible with HTC Sync

Its self explanatory as far as installing and operating.

Edit:

In the cases where neither pdanet nor easyteather will work try this forum thread.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=57267267#post57267267

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. You should consider linking to easyteather, and explain exactly how it would solve the question.

Comment: @RyanConrad the answer is simply wrong.

Comment: You didn't read my question *(I put links to my phone model)*. Your software doesn't use the standard bluetooth method, so it require custom software on android and windows. My phone is a java phone, but not an android phone, it can't run software as long it is not a plain jar file.

Comment: It doesn't matter if its right. We have standards for answers and i was asking that they be followed. It might not be the answer for you, but it may help someone else.

Comment: If your phone is not an android phone, your question does not belong here.

Comment: @RyanConrad : It is on topic because I want to reverse-tether, on my **[android tablet](http://www.samsung.com/fr/consumer/mobile-phones/tablets/galaxy-tab-s/SM-T700NZWAXEF)** *(Only Wi-Fi and bluetooth)* to a **[non android phone](http://www.samsung.com/fr/consumer/mobile-phones/mobiles/bar/GT-B2100SRIXEF)** *(using the service defined by the bluetooth standard)*. I never wanted to reverse-tether my [phone](http://www.samsung.com/fr/consumer/mobile-phones/mobiles/bar/GT-B2100SRIXEF), but I need to tether using [it](http://www.samsung.com/fr/consumer/mobile-phones/mobiles/bar/GT-B2100SRIXEF).